# Why is the reputation required to answer a question enormously high at 50?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

I appreciate the level of professionalism here, but why is the reputation required to answer a question enormously high at 50 ?

I am a professionally experienced expert and because of the threshold to comment is so enormously high > 50 , I am just sitting on valuable comments that would save your users a lot of time and trouble, not to mention better security. So why so high ?

Answer (score 16):

No reputation is required to answer a question; from the [list of privileges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges):

> 1 **create posts** Ask a question or contribute an answer

(And you presumably know this, since [you’ve answered questions on other Stack Exchange sites](https://askubuntu.com/users/792234/marc-cox).)

50 reputation points are required to comment, and the reasons are [explained on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/285232).

We look forward to your answers, and once you start answering, it won’t take long before you can comment everywhere!

Comment: ... and comments are not for answering.

Comment: @Stephen Skitt , I think your answer is reasonable ; however, I want to respond to others questions about "Why don't you post more answers and solutions here .." . Just consider the example above where I ask a completely reasonable question, and get attacked with baseless down votes. So as an admin I suggest you consider imposing some sort of penalty or 1 point cost to someone down voting others else this SE is very unlikely to attract new users, comments or solutions.

Comment: @Marc I suspect that your question attracted downvotes because it starts with an incorrect premise (that answering requires 50 rep); that shows that you didn’t do much research before asking it, and that tends to attract downvotes. Please don’t consider downvotes as “attacks”. Also note that I am not an admin (moderator), and even if I were, I wouldn’t be able to change the voting costs. Making question downvotes cost points (same as answer downvotes, except on Meta) has been discussed in the past, see Meta.SE.

Comment: @MarcCox in addition to everything Stephen said, note that downvoting answers [_does_ have a -1 point cost to the downvoter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). We're a bit obsessed with the signal-to-noise ratio here. These sites were set up to fix perceived problems of forums and one of those is that the useful information is lost in a sea of exploratory questions and comments. This is why we require that answers provide a full answer and why it is standard practice to downvote answers that do not. I know this is weird for new users, but it does work!

Answer (score 6):

To get a reputation higher than 50, all you need is five more up votes than down votes on answers given, or four and at least one accepted answer.

Judging by [your user page on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/426437/marc-cox), you currently have *zero* posted answers.

If you are as full of valuable answers and comments as you claim to be, providing a couple of good, useful answers to questions on the unix.stackexchange.com site shouldn't be hard.